# How can I upload multiple images to twitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter

I am really new to nodejs and javascript. I am trying to create a twitter bot that post tweets with two images. However, all implementations I have came across use single media upload that only helps with a single image file.

```js
const Twitter = require("twitter")
const fs = require("fs")

const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
})

const imageData1 = fs.readFileSync("./quote.jpg"); 
const imageData2 = fs.readFileSync("./meaning.jpg"); // the second image i want to upload

client.post("media/upload", {media: imageData1}, function(error, media, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    const status = {
      status: "I tweeted from Node.js!",
      media_ids: media.media_id_string
    }
    console.log(media)

    client.post("statuses/update", status, function(error, tweet, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully tweeted an image!")
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Any help about a different approach or anything that i am doing wrong is appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with the [Twit library](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)

You need to upload each image individually, then add the id for this new piece of media to an array. When all images are uploaded, call the statuses/update endpoint with the array of media ids, and the images will be attached to the tweet

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Twit({
    consumer_key: '<CONSUMER_KEY>',
    consumer_secret: '<CONSUMER_SECRET>',
    access_token: '<ACCESS_TOKEN>',
    access_token_secret: '<ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET>'
});

const files = ['image1.png', 'image2.png'];
const status = 'This tweet has multiple images';
tweetImages(files, status);

function tweetImages(files, status) {
  let mediaIds = new Array();
  files.forEach(function(file, index) { 
    uploadMedia(file, function(mediaId) {
      mediaIds.push(mediaId);
      if (mediaIds.length === files.length) {
        updateStatus(mediaIds, status);
      }
    });
  });
};

function uploadMedia(file, callback) {
  client.post('media/upload', { media: fs.readFileSync(file).toString("base64") }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (!err) {
      let mediaId = data.media_id_string;
      callback(mediaId);
    } else {
      console.log(`Error occured uploading content\t${err}`);
      process.exit(-1);
    }
  });
}

function updateStatus(mediaIds, status) {
  let meta_params = {media_id: mediaIds[0]};
  client.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
    if (!err) {
      let params = { status: status, media_ids: mediaIds};
      client.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`Error occured updating status\t${err}`);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`Error creating metadata\t${err}`);
      process.exit(-1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph! It is really helpful. I for the time instead used Python version of doing the process, there it was as easy as inputting an additional entry in the media files list.